# What does `,` do in index box?

Tags: python

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(X[:50, 0], X[:50, 1],
            color='red', marker='o', label='setosa')
```

This code I got from `Python Machine Learning`.
But I don't understand what do `X[:50, 0]` and `X[:50, 1]` mean?

I checked about slicing in another SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation). But nowhere they have mentioned the `,` in the index box.

Comment: That notation is peculiar to [`numpy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing)

Comment: @MosesKoledoye The notation is *implemented* by numpy, but any class can take advantage of it, as Uriel's answer shows.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye although it is supported by python, and not used anywhere but `numpy`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `instance[indice]` syntax triggers a call for `instance.__getitem__` with `indice` as the argument.

This shortcut allows also the use of the syntax `x:y:z` to represent `slice(x, y, z)`, which is usually how it is used, but it could be fitted also for other types of indexes, like tuples or strings, as long as your `__getitem__` supports these.

In this code it is used as part of numpy's way to slice 2-dimensional arrays, with the tuple containing the slices for each dimensions.

---

For future reference, you can test with this class:

```
>>> class sliced:
...     def __getitem__ (self, index):
...             print(index)

>>> d = sliced()

>>> d[:50, 1]
(slice(None, 50, None), 1)
```

for that particular case, the comma makes the index a tuple (like `1, 2` would if typed in the REPL), whose first item is the `:50` which is evaluated as a slice with no start, end at `50` and no step specified (the `x:y:z` notation fills `None` in the blanks, and does not require the second `:`).

Comment: @roganjosh slices have start, stop, and step arguments.  They default to None if not present.

Comment: Since the question is about the comma, you might want to specifically point out that the comma makes the index a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

built-in python list indexing hasn't something like `X[:50, 1]`. [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) module added this syntax to it's array class. actually this type of indexing introduced in `MATLAB`. see [here](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) for more information